# WooCommerce - Why is shop page going to a redirect loop?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Got WooCommerce installed and it's working fine if visitors go to: website.com/product-category/store/. "store" is a category I've set. But when I try going to website.com/shop, I get a "This webpage has a redirect loop" and the url changes to website.com/shop44/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the redirect problem your having is the result of one of the following:

1. site url record in the wp-options table
2. settings in Woo Commerce
3. DNS settings

using or NOT using the **www** subdomain.

For example, in the

Then either the site URL record in the database points to the domain that is being forwarded or a setting in woo commerce points to the domain that is being forwarded.

How to fix it.

1. Check your DNS settings. See if the DNS settings  http://www.domain.com forwards to http://domain.com or vice versa.
2. Check ****Woo Commerce > Settings > *some* URL setting**.
3. Check your database go to **PHP MyAdmin** > open table **wp_options**.The first record in the table is **site URL**. There is also a URL record on the second page... check that too.

If these are not all the same url then change them to be consistent.

Lastly, your domain can can also be forwarded in the wp_config file, however it's not recommended.

*Redirect 301 /wp-config.php http://www.domain.com/* **or** *Redirect 301 /wp-config.php http://domain.com/*

Comment: Hey thanks, your instructions gave me some clues. So the issue was being caused by a plugin.. fixed this in database table "redirection_items". But I'm still not sure whcih plugin was causing it...

Comment: This is a good SQL command to keep handy if you have sites with a lot of plugins or if you loose access to the admin area... It disables all plugins via the database. `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';`

Comment: Bit late, but I'm having the same issue, I believe this is default WooCommerce behaviour (changing the redirect URL to the default /shop page).

Comment: iThemes Security ( better wordpress security ) is a popular plugin which has a default setting that can cause this problem with woocommerce. **Settings>SSL>Front End SSL Mode** ( set to off for use with woo and SSL)